# Get an array with specific formate in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on an array with specific formate. i have a form in table with input fields and a dropdown in a single tr like

```
 <tr><td>input 4 name</td><td>input 4 nic</td><td>input 4 email</td><td>drpdown</td></tr>
```

but there is a button which can add any number of tr's as above so once user add more than one row with the help of add row button and then put the data like

```
<tr><td>name1</td><td>nic1</td><td>email1</td><td>option one from drpdown</td></tr>
<tr><td>name2</td><td>nic2</td><td>email2</td><td>option two from drpdown</td></tr>
<tr><td>name3</td><td>nic3</td><td>email3</td><td>option one from drpdown</td></tr>
```

user can add any number of rows but in above example we assume he just need to add three so he did, now when user after put all the data and submit the form, eacd data from each row in the table should save in mysql table in their respective fields in my above case three rows in mysql table. for that i have an array of all those multiple fields and but the structure of array is not fine and thats what i need to solve. below is the array i need to get and then after that will be the array what i in real get and neet to make it correct

what i need is and the reason why i need it like this so that i could easily insert into db

```
Array
(

   [row1] => Array
   (
    [0] => name1
    [1] => nic1
    [2] => email1
   )

   [row2] => Array
   (
    [0] => name2
    [1] => nic2
    [2] => email2
   )
   [row3] => Array
   (
    [0] => name3
    [1] => nic3
    [2] => email3
   )

 )
```

but what i get is

```
  Array
  (

    [row1] => Array
    (
        [0] => name1
        [1] => name2
        [2] => name3
    )

    [row2] => Array
     (
        [0] => nic1
        [1] => nic2
        [2] => nic3
     )

    [row3] => Array
    (
        [0] => email1
        [1] => email2
        [2] => email3            
    )

 )
```

here is now the script for it.

```
  var spoc_name_array = {};
    var inputs = $(".spocName");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){


    spoc_name_array = $(inputs[i]).val();
    var hiddeninput = '<input type="hidden" name="spocNames[]" value="'+spoc_name_array+'">';
    //append the new hidden input to your hidden form
     $('#services_hidden_form').append(hiddeninput);

    }

    var spoc_nic_array = {};
    var inputs = $(".spocNic");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    //alert($(inputs[i]).val());

    spoc_nic_array = $(inputs[i]).val();
    var hiddeninput = '<input type="hidden" name="spocnic[]" value="'+spoc_nic_array+'">';
    //append the new hidden input to your hidden form
     $('#services_hidden_form').append(hiddeninput);

    }

    var spoc_email_array = {};
    var inputs = $(".spocEmial");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){

    spoc_email_array = $(inputs[i]).val();
    var hiddeninput = '<input type="hidden" name="spocemail[]" value="'+spoc_email_array+'">';
    //append the new hidden input to your hidden form
     $('#services_hidden_form').append(hiddeninput);

    }
```

i am stuck here now so dont know what to do to get rid of this issue. Thanks in advance for any kind of help. if you think i can insert data into mysql tablefrom the already available array with logical code on php page then gv me idea i am open for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var i=1;
var finalArray=new Array();
$('tr').each(function(){
    arr=[];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).text());
    });
    finalArray['row'+i]=arr;
    i++;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMrhn/1/)

Comment: yes but where to put this code as the array i get is after submit the form but i can not figure out that where to put that code to get what i need cab u edit my code